# Value of module variable is restarted after initialization in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a global variable in python, but it seems that I don't understand well the concept. I have created a `my_connection` vairable in a module called `mysql_example` and then I have initialized it inside the `MysqlExample` class, but after that, the value is cleared. My `mysql_example` module have the following code:

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector as mysql

my_connection = None


class MysqlExample(object):

    def __init__(self, config : dict ):
        my_connection = mysql.Connect( **config )
        my_connection.autocommit = True
    
    def close(self):
        self._endExtraction()
        my_connection.close()
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self._id_extraction = self._startExtraction()
        return self
        
    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb ):
        self.close()
    
    def _startExtraction(self):
        cur = my_connection.cursor()
        cur.execute( '''select * from simple_test''' )
        return cur.lastrowid
        
    def _endExtraction(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        cur = my_connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('''select * from simple_test''', 
            { 'id_extraction' : self._id_extraction, 
              'end_date' : datetime.datetime.now() } )
        self._lock.release()
```

and the main call is like this:

```
with MysqlExample({ "host" : "XXXX", 
                              "database" : "XXXXX",
                              "user" : "XXXXX", 
                              "password" : "super-secret-password" }) as my_example: 
    print("hello")
```

The error the code shows is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

And that is because the value `my_connection` is re-initialized in apparently every method call. Is that the usual behaviour in python???

Comment: You are missing the global keyword in any function that utilises "myconnection" https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Comment: When you do `my_connection = mysql.Connect( **config )` in the `__init__`, all it does is create a new ***local*** variable to that method. What you probably wanted is `self.my_connection = ...` and then all other methods to reference that `self.my_connection`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Global keyword to inform the `__init__` function that my_connection belongs to the global namespace

```
def __init__(self, config : dict ):
    global my_connection
    my_connection = mysql.Connect( **config )
    my_connection.autocommit = True
```

Comment: Honestly, it looks more like OP wants `my_connection` to be an instance variable...

Comment: Yes i agree, the code could be better organised and better optimised. My answer is to purely address the reason to why the error occurs, considering the opening remark is "I am trying to create a global variable".

Comment: Yes, @AKX, it should be an instance variable. I am trying to do some stuff in multithreading, but the class I am developing closes the connection and I do not why. So I was trying to move the connection to a global variable when I got this error. That I should already know, by the way

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to do that. You have to choose what kind of variable `my_connection` is and then stick to that choice. It can be:

- an instance variable. It is only declared and used inside objects of the class, and each object has its own connection. Init/close should look like:

  ```
    class MysqlExample(object):
        def __init__(self, config : dict ):
            self.my_connection = mysql.Connect( **config )
            self.my_connection.autocommit = True

        def close(self):
            self._endExtraction()
            self.my_connection.close()
  ```
- a global variable. It should be declared, initialized and closed *outside of any object*. Of course you are responsable for initializing it before any attempt to use it, and close it when done.

  ```
    def init_connection(config : dict ):
        global my_connection
        my_connection = mysql.Connect( **config )
        my_connection.autocommit = True

    def close_connection(self):
        my_connection.close()

    class MysqlExample(object):
        ...
  ```

Your current code mixed both ways. That means that every new object will create a new global `my_connection` object (and leak the previous one), but the first object to die will close the global connection. Definitely a wrong design...

Comment: Ok, thanks: I've checked the code and a instance variable would do the trick